# How to set up ajax crud in laravel 5.4 with dynamic input fields

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, crud, laravel-5.4

My goal is to make a post CRUD that has a variable ammount of inputfields. with a normal CRUD setup i run in to the problem that the variable fields vanish when the user refreshes the page or when the post doesn't get trough te validation. To fix this i was thinking about using ajax to make it possible to save the added inputfields directly into the database. How would i go about this?

The inputfields belong to the post so the post should exist when saving the inputfields. Should i start with an empty saved post to accomplish this or is this bad practice?

Posts in the db:

```
post
- id
- title
```

inputfields in the db:

```
inputfield
- id
- post_id
- title
- body
```

how i see it:

- user creates a new post (this stores an empty post in the db).
- the inputfields are added and stored in the db using ajax with it's own CRUD on the create page
- user fills in any forms and input fields also with ajax so it can be updated inbetween .
- when the post is stored any empty inputfields are destroyed.

I hope someone can help as i have no real jquery and ajax experience.

Comment: If you're going to instantiate an empty record for `inputfield`, you can return the `id` for that new record. Then, the CRUD method to update the record can just add new info to the same `id` (instead of adding a new one a deleting the old blank one).

Comment: ok, but i don't want to show the empty records in the show page. Should i use an if statement to see if the record is empty before showing it then?